# Firestore serverTimestamp() undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Problem**

I have a callable cloud function set up which writes to Firestore using the Admin SDK (node.js):

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.myFunction = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    await admin.firestore().doc("/test").create({
        timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    });

})
```

Testing this using the emulators. Also my packages are:

```
"firebase-admin": "^11.2.1",
"firebase-functions": "^4.0.2",
"firebase-tools": "11.16.0"
```

I am getting this error in my emulator logs:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'serverTimestamp')
```

I recently updated the admin SDK and the firebase-tools to the versions above, then the problem started occurring. I tried reinstalling firebase-tools and the admin SDK without luck.

Anyone have an idea of what I could try?

Answer (score 10):

Found the API reference [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/FieldValue.html). Instead of `timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` it should be `timestamp: Firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

Also import: `const { Firestore } = require("firebase-admin/firestore");`